# mongodb 2dsphere index fails on MultiPolygon (malformed geometry)

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geojson

I am struggling to undestand why the following indexing fails:

```
> db.mycollection.ensureIndex({geometry:"2dsphere"})
{
        "err" : "Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:{ type: \"MultiPolygon\", coordinates: [ [ [ [ -0.097262623621224, 51.52157883707353 ], [ -0.096489562220012, 51.52027612781475 ], [ -0.095242927823793, 51.52050373756695 ], [ -0.094744446266, 51.5205960952269 ], [ -0.094366848238175, 51.5206711083638 ], [ -0.094478602055745, 51.51976097300852 ], [ -0.095268219478419, 51.51892749907517 ], [ -0.095057671259463, 51.51823866169356 ], [ -0.09590752332937, 51.51675447483272 ], [ -0.094917254103398, 51.51658818255699 ], [ -0.095455170681833, 51.51544167621788 ], [ -0.09577124973446099, 51.51496874589772 ], [ -0.096562908994151, 51.5148429136635 ], [ -0.097957187488107, 51.51553859434178 ], [ -0.097828201440347, 51.51660172221631 ], [ -0.09972288755426, 51.5167693068687 ], [ -0.099643129935966, 51.51745174289048 ], [ -0.099140106492407, 51.51776283078856 ], [ -0.098174109996819, 51.51789906140922 ], [ -0.098017592779996, 51.5175476311896 ], [ -0.097562458108715, 51.51768194540703 ], [ -0.097737151858934, 51.519666041172 ], [ -0.0978402555155, 51.51992164186168 ], [ -0.098548930349501, 51.51973516284531 ], [ -0.098498300867191, 51.52053989289254 ], [ -0.09761991242012499, 51.52069031743765 ], [ -0.097262623621224, 51.52157883707353 ] ] ] ] }",
        "code" : 16572,
        "n" : 0,
        "connectionId" : 61,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I checked all the related question on SO but couldn't figure out the problem. They all pointed out to the lon,lat order and the format of coordinates. I am using Mongodb 2.4.

one possible explanation can be this but I'm not sure

[MongoDB version 2.6 still fails on 2dsphere geoindexing citing inability to extract geokeys and possible malformed geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398292/mongodb-version-2-6-still-fails-on-2dsphere-geoindexing-citing-inability-to-extr)

Answer (score 0):

The Multipolygon geometry type is not supported in MongoDB 2.4 (see [Geospatial enhancements in MongoDB 2.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/2.6/#geospatial-enhancements)).

Please note that as of this writing, MongoDB 2.4 is not a supported version anymore. If this is for a new project, I would recommend using the latest version (currently MongoDB 3.6.2) to ensure that you are not affected by any historical issues that were fixed in newer versions.